# OPC UA TranslateBrowsePathsToNodeIds() Service

Tags: opc-ua

I know that the TranslateBrowsePathsToNodeIds() service can be used to program against Type Definitions and, by extension, retrieve the NodeIds of the components/properties of a Node.

I have two questions.

1) Does the last element of the RelativePath structure require a valid targetName, i.e cannot be null?

2) Is there any prescribed behavior for when the path can be resolved successfully down two different branches, i.e the program can select different nodes at an intermediate path and still follow the next sequence of paths successfully?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, the final element can have an *empty* targetName. According to the spec:

> The final element may have an empty targetName. In this situation all targets of the references identified by the referenceTypeId are the targets of the RelativePath.
>
> The targetName shall be specified for all other elements.

2) Again, from the spec:

> If a Node has multiple targets with the same BrowseName, the Server shall return a list of NodeIds. However, since one of the main purposes of this Service is to support programming against type definitions, the NodeId of the Node based on the type definition of the starting Node is returned as the first NodeId in the list.

I realize you're asking about intermediary duplicate browse names but I think this still applies; you just end up with multiple targets returned from the call.